# Need a confirmation that subclassing UIAlertView is legal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, app-store

I have been reading around trying to find a definitive answer on if subclassing UIAlertView to change the background color is ok with Apple.

I know the apple documentation states:

> Subclassing Notes The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is
>   and does not support subclassing.  The view hierarchy for this class
>   is private and must not be modified.

Yet I have seen many people attempting it and some stating that they have done it with no problem.

Can someone give a solid Yes or No answer as to if I should do this or not in my app.

- I know I will have to take it with a grain since it is the app store and the last time one of my apps was rejected and I appealed the Apple representative only stated, "The app store is an ever changing marketplace where acceptance is at the discretion of the team." *click*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody can give you a solid yes or no.  Just because an app on the store does something doesn't mean you will be accepted for doing the same thing.  My gut says as long as your alert behaves like the standard one and isn't horribly ugly, you probably will be fine.